# Compute Slope for Each Point in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Using Python 2.7: So I have this dataframe called `edge_err` that looks like this:

```py
# Simplified DF
d = {'model_id': [1, 2, 4, 8, 16], 't_err':[.715130, .236947, .002106, .001043, .000512]}
pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Slope is the variable I want to compute

      model_id  t_err   slope
0         1  0.715130   0 
1         2  0.236947   1.593640
2         4  0.002106   6.813878
3         8  0.001043   1.013115
4        16  0.000512   1.026592
```

And I want to calculate the slope between the each observation across `model_id` and `t_err`. Currently my code to add the `slope` column looks like this:

```py
def slope(x, y):
        slope_list = []
        for xi in range(0, len(x)-1):
                denom = x[xi+1] - x[xi]
                num = y[xi+1] - y[xi]
                slope = num / denom
                slope_list.append(slope)

        return slope_list

    transformx = [np.log10(1/float(x)) for x in edge_err.model_id.tolist()]
    transformy = [np.log10(x) for x in edge_err.t_err.tolist()]

    edge_err['slope'] = [0] + slope(transformx, transformy)
```

I have to transform these numbers for a particular reason not really related to the computation of the slope, hence `transformx` and `transformy`

But I'm conviced there is a `pandas` way to accomplish this. I have seen other questions address this problem but can't quite fit it to my circumstance. How would I go about computing the slope between each point?

The first observation should remain in the table but either have a slope value of `0` or `NaN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

logarithmic functions are for some reason not included in pandas, but it's simple (and efficient) to use apply with numpy functions.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'model_id': [1, 2, 4, 8, 16], 't_err':[.715130, .236947, .002106, .001043, .000512]}
d = pd.DataFrame(d)
transformx = -d['model_id'].apply(np.log10)
transformy = d['t_err'].apply(np.log10)
denom = transformx.diff()
num = transformy.diff()
slope = (num / denom).fillna(0)


slope
 0    0.000000
 1    1.593641
 2    6.813915
 3    1.013766
 4    1.026523
 dtype: float64
```

If NaN is sufficient, you can simply drop the `fillna` function call.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do all in one chain using [assign()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
edge_err.assign(transformx = -np.log10(edge_err.model_id)
            ,   transformy = np.log10(edge_err.t_err)) \
        .assign(slope = lambda x: (x.transformy.diff())/(x.transformx.diff()))
#   model_id     t_err  transformx  transformy     slope
#0         1  0.715130    -0.00000   -0.145615       NaN
#1         2  0.236947    -0.30103   -0.625349  1.593641
#2         4  0.002106    -0.60206   -2.676542  6.813915
#3         8  0.001043    -0.90309   -2.981716  1.013766
#4        16  0.000512    -1.20412   -3.290730  1.026523
```